# How to use different primefaces versions in one project?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

In my project I have to implement a page which use primefaces v6.1 but other pages are written in primefaces version 3.
Its hard to update versions for other pages, on the other hand i dont want to use v3 for the new page.

First i have a idea; manipulating **primefaces-p.taglib.xml** which is in META-INF,
`<namespace>http://primefaces6version.org/ui</namespace>` . Try to use in the xhtml page:
`xmlns:p="http://primefaces6version.org/ui"` and components now can be in primefaces 6 versions! But its not worked, i dont know why.

Is there any idea how to use different primefaces versions in same project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not easily possible and would require a lot of work. It would e.g. require fully refactored (classes renamed etc) version of PrimeFaces including everything in the taglibs and more. You could try just creating a customized PF version for just the datatable, but personally I'd bite the apple and upgrade the application.